# rosservice call error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20through%20a%20Cartesian%20pose%20trajectory?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22pr2_controllers%2FTutorials%2FMoving+the+arm+through+a+Cartesian+pose+trajectory%22) and configure the service and the c++ code (and make it).
At the end I could not call the service by:

> rosservice call
> /ExecuteCartesianIKTrajectory --
> "{header: { frame_id: /base_link},
> poses: [{position: [0.76, -0.19,
> 0.83], orientation:[0.02, -0.09, 0.0, 1.0]}, {position: [0.59, -0.36, 0.93], orientation: [0.65, -0.21, .38,
> .62]}]}"

I received:

> ERROR: Service
> [/ExecuteCartesianIKTrajectory] is not
> available.

But I can do:

> rossrv show
> ik_trajectory_tutorial/ExecuteCartesianIKTrajectory

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41569/rosservice-call-error/) by [Amit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3037/amit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think rossrv show just indicates if a service of type "ik_trajectory_tutorial/ExecuteCartesianIKTrajectory" exists. The error tells you that your service node (the node that offers that service) is not running...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-16**:
rosservice list gives the running services.